# Using intellij with dart, directories under src don't recognize dart files correctly

Tags: dart, intellij-idea

I have subdirectories under lib/src, and lib/src is tagged as the source root. Files under subdirectories are not recognized correctly by intellij as dart files and do not have source highlighting.

I have also made sure the module is enabled for dart.

Any ideas?

Comment: Oddly, the file that is not recognized correctly is base.dart. Other files are OK.

Comment: What file type is set for base.dart file?